# Filter out only latest entries, for Orders

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, where-clause

I'm trying to write a query where i select the latest changes on a specific Order in an OrderTable
ex.

```
OrderID|       ChangeDate      | 
-------|-----------------------|
Order1 |2013-03-17 14:40:47.000|
Order2 |2013-03-12 12:34:09.000|
Order3 |2013-03-20 18:30:12.000|
Order1 |2013-03-20 16:09:09.000|
Order2 |2013-03-20 12:39:49.000|
```

Say (from the Example above), what i need is the latest entries of Order1,Order2 and Order3.
Has anyone been in a similar situation?
I am really greatefull for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select OrderID,max(ChangeDate) as LatestDate
from yourTable
group by OrderID
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches but assuming you want the whole record and not just the `max( date)` per order id you can use row_number.

```
WITH CTE
(
SELECT 
  OrderID, 
  changeDate, 
  ChangeValue,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVer (Partition BY OrderID order by ChangeDate Desc) rn

FROM order 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE where rn = 1
```

Note: This returns exactly one record per order. This may or may not be an issue if you have a tie for max change date

Comment: the comma between `partition` and `order by` needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
SELECT OrderID,
       MAX(ChangeDate) as LatestEntry
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY OrderID
```